# Is there a TCl equivalent of PHP's header tag

Tags: tcl

Can anyone tell what do we use in TCL for redirecting to another page as in case of Header tag in PHP

I already used ::ncgi::redirect but its not redirecting automatically

Comment: Can you paste a small snippet of the code where you used ncgi::redirect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try using `::ncgi::redirect` at the top of the code. Basically, it should come before writing any response because it returns a header to the browser. There should not be any `puts` statements before `::ncgi::redirect`
2. Try returning the header like this: `::ncgi::header text/html Location $url`. Again, this should be done before printing any response.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if the solution worked for you :)